# ag-grid-angular v26.0.0: Need to add multiple (2) inputs in a filterOptions

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

As per https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/, if we want to have 2 inputs for a filter option, we need to have 'numberOfInputs: 2'

Ex:

```
this.columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'age',
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            filterOptions: [
                {
                    displayKey: 'inRange',
                    numberOfInputs: 2,
                }
            ]
        }
    }
];
```

But, this does not work in ag-grid-angular v26.0.0. Any help to resolve this will be very much appreciated.

Please note:

i) I cannot use **agNumberColumnFilter** as I had to manipulate the comparator (used textCustomComparator) which was not possible as explained in [Why is the ag-grid filter comparator not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072915/why-is-the-ag-grid-filter-comparator-not-executing)

ii) I have put **displayName** & **predicate** function for filterOptions, but no use.

Comment: Based upon the documentation, `filterOptions` should be an object adhering to the `IFilterOptionDef` interface - not an array of such objects

Comment: The interface declaration for IFilterOptionDef (in node_modules\ag-grid-community\dist\lib\interfaces\iFilter.d.ts) does not have 'numberOfInputs' field
`
export interface IFilterOptionDef {
    displayKey: string;
    displayName: string;
    test: (filterValue: any, cellValue: any) => boolean;
    hideFilterInput?: boolean;
}
`

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest? I'm on 27 myself and see many differences in the documented interface vs what I'm running as well.

Comment: I cannot update as there are lot of dependencies which breaks when I update to 28.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to get access to newer functionality until you upgrade

Comment: Updated to 28.0.0 and filterOptions as 
            filterOptions: [
                {
                    displayKey: 'inRange',
                    displayName: 'In Range',
                    numberOfInputs: 2,
                    predicate: ([fv1, fv2], cellValue) => {
                      return fv1 <= cellValue.data && cellValue.data <= fv2;
                    }
                }
            ]
   It is working.
   1 query: How to have locale specific display name (is there a way to use ag-grids built-in methods)?